# How to interpret the S21 phase measured by LCA or VNA?

Tags: phase-shift, vna

I have measured the S21 phase of my device, which came as below. I would like to know if this phase is with reference to the input or with reference to the DC?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "the reference to DC"? It's the phase relative to the calibration of your Vector Network Analyzer, usually through/open/short/load. If properly calibrated, the S21 reads 0 dB at 0 degrees across the band if you connect the measurement coaxial cables directly together (eg: by connecting them with the "through" calibration standard).

Provided you are properly calibrated, the S21 value at each frequency corresponds to the phase shift and amplitude change of a sinusoidal signal passing through the device at that frequency. A positive phase value for S21 means that the output phase leads the input phase, and a negative value means the output phase lags the input phase (see also [this question and answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465165/phase-of-scattering-parameters)).

Answer (score 1):

> I have measured the S21 phase of my device, which came as below. I would like to know if this phase is with reference to the input or with reference to the DC?

The phase of the measured S21 is with respect to the phase of the through-line calibration piece that was used to calibrate the VNA.

With the DUT (device under test) showing 3.6 cycles in 1 GHz, that's equivalent to an electrical length of about 3.6 ft (light goes at about 1 ns per foot), or in a typical plastic-insulated cable a physical length of about 2.2 ft / .67 m.

Answer (score 0):

S21 is defined as the ratio of the power leaving port 2 and the power entering port 1 of a two-port device. Therefore the phase of S21 is the phase of the power leaving port 2 with the power entering port 1 as the reference.

Answer (score 0):

A response shows 3.6 full 360deg cycles of phase shift from 1 to 2 GHz.  This means the propagation delay of your device under test including cables before calibration with the std. calibration methods is the time it takes to shift 1 GHz thru 3.6 wavelengths. If using coax at c=2e8 m/s = wl * 1GHz then using wavelength, wl = 20cm. Thus with 3.6 waves for this frequency span ,  I can estimate your cable delay is at most is 20/3.6 cm. You need to null this delay with some calibration by replacing the D.U.T. (Device under test) with a thru connector.